# RestKit - Request blocks until previous call completes

Tags: restkit, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, restkit-0.20

I am seeing an issue with RestKit where an outstanding remote request will cause other requests to queue up and block until the previous one completes.  I have read that RestKit defaults AFNetworking's `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount` value to 5, but I am encountering blocking with just a single outstanding request.

Does the current version of RestKit still default this to 5, and if so, what could be causing my lack of concurrent requests?

RestKit 0.20.3

**Request**

```
- (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation*) getUser {
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    NSDictionary *items = [objectManager.HTTPClient defaultHeaders];
    NSString *auth = [items objectForKey:@"Authorization"];

    if (auth == nil) {
        NSLog(@"You must login first\n");
        return nil;
    }

    auth = [auth stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Bearer " withString:@""];

    NSMutableString *path = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"/users?accessToken=%@", auth];
    return [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodGET path:path parameters:nil];
}

- (void) getUser:(void ( ^ ) ( RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , RKMappingResult *mappingResult ))success failure:(void ( ^ ) ( RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error ))failure {
    RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *requestOperation = [self getUser];
    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];

    [requestOperation start];
}
```

The former is a helper used in testing, and the latter is actually called by Production code.  I don't see any place in my code where the Queue size is set explicitly.

Comment: Be specific about the version number you're using. Have you logged the concurrent count of the queue? Also, show the code you're using, sometimes the queue size is explicitly set to 1.

Comment: @Wain Updated. I don't set the queue size anywhere, and I'm just making a standard `appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:method:path:parameters:` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RKObjectRequestOperation` contains an internal queue (`responseMappingQueue`) which is shared amongst all instances. This queue is explicitly set with a concurrency count of 1, but it's just used for mapping, not for the URL connections.

Looking at what you're doing, calling `start` on the operation directly, you most likely want to think about adding the operation to a queue so that you can manage them better. Because you aren't using the object manager to run the operations the concurrent count of 5 that you refer to doesn't apply. Look at using `enqueueObjectRequestOperation:` to run the operations.

Comment: So I should call `enqueueObjectRequestOperation` with the `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` instead of explicitly calling `start` on it?

Comment: Yes, that would be the recommended approach. You could create your own operation queue and add it to that but using the object manager is better. Generally, I wouldn't use the operations directly, I'd have the object manager to everything...